# XML parsing with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I want to display xml with ajax. Can help overcome the problems I faced.
sorry, I can not write code that a lot of the posts column.

http://pastebin.com/vwZz1XRd

Comment: What you have tried so far...?

Comment: I have tried parsing with ajax. script has been in post, if you can help me?